# Which postgres schema and relation lists connections to the database?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm attempting to view a history of connection coming to my company's database. It's an Amazon Redshift server.

I've listed a number of relations, but there are none that immediately pop out as useful.

```
\dt information_schema.
\dt pg_catalog.
```

Are there any schemas, views, variables, or tables I can query for this information?

Comment: It's not a Postgresql 8 server, it's Redshift. They share a common ancestor, but have many differences and are definitely not the same product. What do you actually want to see - information about user connections, or information about schemas and objects?

Comment: @Nathan Griffiths Thanks for the clarification. I'm more interested in the info about the current and past connections made to the server.

Comment: I cannot speak about Redshift, but in PostgreSQL you can get such information only through the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view the recent history of connection information to the Redshift cluster by querying the Redshift system table [STL_CONNECTION_INFO](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_CONNECTION_LOG.html). This table logs authentication attempts, connections and disconnections.

STL tables contain only about 2-5 days worth of history. If you want to retain this data long term, you should look at setting up [Database Audit Logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/db-auditing.html), which will log this information permanently to S3.